# Reading Arduino serial data in Octave on Mac

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I am trying to read serial port data generated by Arduino in Octave on Mac. I installed and loaded the instrument-control package for the same. I used this piece of code to check if the package was installed properly

```
if (exist("serial") == 3) disp("Serial: Supported") else disp("Serial: Unsupported") endif
```

I do get an output saying Serial: Supported.

I am following the tutorial [here](http://irnas.eu/other%20projects/2015/06/04/serial-octave-arduino) for step by step guidance.
I next use `s=serial('portname')` to create a serial port object. However, I am not sure what name to use instead of COM5 on Windows for Mac.

I checked and my Arduino is connected to cu.usbmodem1421 so I tried following 3 options a)cu.usbmodem1421 b) usbmodem1421 c)1421 but in each case I get an error saying "serial: Error opening the interface: No such file or directory".

Could anyone tell me what port name I can use or if there are any suggestions for the big picture problem as to how to read Arduino serial data in Octave (on Mac)? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely need the full canonical pathname for the port:

```
/dev/cu.usbmodem1421
```

On the Mac, as in Linux and other Unix derivatives, most devices, serial ports included, are special files in the `/dev` directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried /dev/tty.usbmodem1421 and it worked!

Comment: According to the rules of TTY naming for connecting to an external device from inside the Mac you should use the `/dev/cu.*` variant. It's the same physical devices as the `/dev/tty.*` variant, but the line control is handled differently. The `/dev/tty.*` variant is intended for incoming connections to the Mac (a text-based login prompt).